# how to fill two or more selects with the same option elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to add the same options elements to more than one select, using one JavaScript function.

```html
<select id="select1" name="select1"></select>
<select id="select2" name="select2"></select>
```

I want selects become:

```html
<select id="select1" name="select1"> 
  <option value="0">Txt1</option>
  <option value="1">Txt2</option>
  <option value="2">Txt3</option>
</select>
<select id="select2" name="select2"> 
  <option value="0">Txt1</option>
  <option value="1">Txt2</option>
  <option value="2">Txt3</option>
</select>
```

Here is part of function to fill selects with options:

```
function window_onload(){
  var SpecTxt = new Array("Txt1","Txt2","Txt3");
    for(var i=0; i<SpecTxt.length; i++) {
      var oOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
          oOption.text = SpecTxt[i];
          oOption.value=i;
          select1.add(oOption);  // Option to first SELECT
          select2.add(oOption);  // Option to second SELECT
    }
}
```

But I've got Internet Explorer Script Error "Invalid argument", result is only one first option in "select1" and no options in "select2". If I remove from **function window_onload()** the last string **select2.add(oOption);**, there are no IE errors and "select1" is filled as must be, but "select2" is empty. How is it possible in JS to add the same options to different SELECTs?

Comment: How are `select1` and `select2` defined in your script? Are you sure you didn't forget something like `select1 = document.getElementById('select1');`?

Comment: The code is sound. You need to do some basic step-by-step debugging. Does the function fire? Do `select1` and `select2` contain the elemental references you think they do? Anything in the console? Etc.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca. It's interesting, but 'select1' and 'select2' are not defined in script. They are defined as select tag ID. I realy don't use 'document.getElementById(  )'. Function works equally with or without 'document.getElementById(  )' and if it's not necessary, I don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

The reason why the Demo didn't work for IE is because it doesn't recognize the property `.valueAsNumber`.

**From:**

```
var opts = qty.valueAsNumber;
```

**To:**

```
var opts = parseInt(qty.value, 10);
```

---

When you create an option within the loop:

```
var oOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
```

That is only one `<option>` not  two `<option>`s. So that is the reason why:

```
select1.add(oOption);  // Succeeds
select2.add(oOption);  // Fails
```

You can either make 2 `<option>`s per loop:

```
var oOption1 = document.createElement("OPTION");
var oOption2 = document.createElement("OPTION");
```

OR try `cloneNode()`. See Demo below:

### Demo

```js
// See HTMLFormControlsCollection
var form = document.forms.ui;
var ui = form.elements;
var qty = ui.qty0;
var s0 = ui.sel0;
var s1 = ui.sel1;

// Declare a counter variable outside of loop
var cnt = 0;

// Add event handler to the change event of the input
qty.onchange = addOpt;

/* Get the value of user input as a number
|| within the for loop...
|| create an <option> tag...
|| add text to it with an incremented offset...
|| add a incremented value to it...
|| then clone it...
|| add original <option> to the first <select>...
|| add duplicate <option> to the second <select>
*/
function addOpt(e) {
  var opts = parseInt(qty.value, 10);
  for (let i = 0; i < opts; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.text = 'Txt' + (cnt + 1);
    opt.value = cnt;
    var dupe = opt.cloneNode(true);
    s0.add(opt);
    s1.add(dupe);
    cnt++;
  }
}
```

```css
input,
select,
option {
  font: inherit
}

input {
  width: 4ch;
}
```

```html
<form id='ui'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter a number in the first form field</legend>
    <input id='qty0' name='qty0' type='number' min='0' max='30'>
    <select id="sel0" name="sel0"></select>
    <select id="sel1" name="sel1"></select>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

### Reference

[**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)

Comment: Function works properly with 2 OPTIONs per loop. Thank you. With ' cloneNode()' I've got the same IE error. But it's enaugh that function code with 2 options works.

Comment: I totally forgot to test IE, I'll see what I can do for that quasi-browser.

Comment: It's on the top of the answer titled **Update**.  It explains what is changed. It's only one line.